# Questions about the definition of lazy

Tags: f#

On line 5633 in prim-types.fs (v1.9.7.8) there is the following type abbreviation:

```
type 'T ``lazy`` = Lazy<'T>
```

I have a few questions about it.

1. What do the double backticks mean?
2. Is this definition equivalent to `type lazy<'T> = Lazy<'T>`? (If not, how is it different?)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The double back ticks are a way of allowing an F# keyword to be used as an identifier.  Another example would be

```
let ``let`` = 42
```

Comment: In fact it allows you to use any string as an identifier, so you're fond of identifiers with question marks (ala Ruby) you can say:

 let ``is good?`` = false 

Though I'm not convinced that this is really a good way to write code.

Answer (score 5):

To answer the second half of your question, generic types in F# can be specified using either the O'Caml-style syntax where the generic parameter precedes the type (e.g `'a list`, `int array`, etc.), or the .NET-style with angle brackets (e.g. `list<'a>`, `array<int>`, etc.), so the two definitions are indeed basically equivalent (except that your version as written is syntactically invalid because `lazy` is a keyword).  For multi-parameter generic types, the O'Caml style is deprecated and will generate a warning (e.g. `let (m:(int,string) Map) = Map.empty` should be rewritten as `let (m:Map<int,string>) = Map.empty`).

Comment: ...or else: `let m = Map.empty<int,string>` which is a bit nicer in my opinion.